# Variables inside an Interface, or an alternative way to add/require variables to various classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project with an ever growing amount of "placeholder assets" (such as ScriptableObjects for Items and Enemies). So I was thinking it would be neat if I could somehow; (1) flag them as being placeholders, and also (2) give them an estimated production cost. In order to parse through all of them during build/play-time and output something like this in the log: "Build contains 125 placeholders, at en estimated cost of 3275 USD."

I was hoping this would be as easy as creating an Interface that I could implement on all my various classes which represent assets/content, to give me these extra fields (e.g. bool isPlaceholder and float costEstimate). Like this:

```
namespace PlaceholderInfo
{
    public interface IPlaceholderInfo
    {
        bool isPlaceholder = false;
        float costEstimate = 0f;
    }
}
```

And then end up with something like this in the Inspector, that I could easy edit for all assets:

[image]

And later to parse through that data, perhaps using this method https://answers.unity.com/questions/863509/how-can-i-find-all-objects-that-have-a-script-that.html - but I'm currently stuck at the FIRST step, as I just learned (the hard way) that Interfaces can't even have fields! :(

What shall I do? Is there another approach I can take?

Comment: Hi, interfaces are indeed designed to be a contract with the outside world - and therefore only contain public methods and properties, even with no implementation.

Comment: So, what you should do, is create a `class`, if you want to make use of n interface, inherit it: `public class PlaceholderInfo: IPlaceholderInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the class that inherit IPlaceholderInfo like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeInfo : IPlaceholderInfo 
{
   public bool isPlaceholder = false;
   public float costEstimate = 0f;
}
```

And after that just add this info to some MonoBehavior class which inherit some interface like this:

```
public interface IDataContainer
{
    IPlaceholderInfo[] GetInfo();
}

public class JustAnotherContainer : MonoBehavior, IDataContainer
{
   [SerializedField] private SomeInfo[] someInfo;

   public IPlaceholderInfo[] GetInfo()
   {
      return someInfo;
   }
}
```

And after that you can find this data like this:

```
public Start()
{
  var data = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<IDataContainer>();

  //or you can use this if you have only 1 object with data
  var info = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<IDataContainer>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm getting this error though: 'JustAnotherContainer' does not implement interface member 'IDataContainer.GetInfo()'. 'JustAnotherContainer.GetInfo()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot about make public this function, I fixed my code. Mark this answer if it helps you

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Now I'm able to attach the JustAnotherContainer to some other Monobehaviour script, and "Some Info" appears beneath it BUT no variables exposed in the Inspector (e.g. the bool and flat). It just says "Some Info".

Comment: Ok, I fix SomeInfo class code, try this version, had to make these variables public

Comment: NM, I had to click the "+" under "Some Info" (in the Inspector) to add one row, and then the properties appeared! But can I have it appear automatically somehow?

Comment: You can change [SerializedField] private SomeInfo[] someInfo; to [SerializedField] private SomeInfo[] someInfo = new SomeInfo[] {new SomeInfo(), new SomeInfo()};

In this variant, you adding 2 objects to the array.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your solution to be able to be attached to ScriptableObjects (instead of Monobehaviours)?

Comment: Yeah, of course, just change SomeInfo classlike this:

public class SomeInfo : ScriptableObject, IPlaceholderInfo 
{
   public bool isPlaceholder = false;
   public float costEstimate = 0f;
}

And you need some changes in other classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217659/discussion-between-geek-girl-x0x0-and-onionfan).